# Add stream meta to a stream via Gstreamer

Tags: c++, metadata, gstreamer

The goal here is to be able to send some metadata (timestamps, objects found per frame) with a stream within a single pipeline or multiple pipelines over network (e.g. RTP UDP).

**Within The pipeline:**
This is straight forward by defining a new `GstMeta` API and register and implement it. Then add it to `GstBuffer`s via buffer probes or another element solely designed for this purpose.

**Multiple pipelines over Network:**
The only solution I have heard about is to add one or more RTP header extension to RTP packets coming out of a payloader. Actually some people decided to transform their Custom GstMeta into those header extensions. But Is This really a good use-case for it?

**There's more ....**
Another idea is to create your own custom media type `video/x-mytype` and for that you will need to write a typefinding function and an autoplugger on top of it, Not to mention a couple of elements to deal with this new type and convert it to other exiting media types. Now that new type should actually have a place where it can handle the meta data I was talking about.

That summarizes my research, Are there any other methods that I am not aware of?

I would definitely appreciate your input on this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hav you found a solution to this in the meantime?

Comment: Kindly, check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to implement a new media type inside gstreamer (e.g. `video/x-h265-with-meta`). This new media type shall have inherent metadata handling capabilities. You can design how it encode/decode the metadata as you see fit in this new type. You would also need write 2 more gstreamer elements. one to convert regular `video/x-h265` to  `video/x-h265-with-meta` (say `muxmymeta`) and the other to reverse such conversion (say `demuxmymeta`). So essentially `muxmymeta` will read the metadata injected in the `GstBuffer*` via `GstMeta` API implementation and encodes in the outgoing stream. `demuxmymeta` will decode such metadata from the stream and add it back to `GstBuffer*`. To ensure that for every encoded h265 frame will have a corresponding meta, `muxmymeta` must have its src caps in this format:

```
video/x-h265
          stream-format: byte-stream
              alignment: au
```

The `byte-stream` is mandatory for network transmission and the `au` alignment forces a whole encoded frame as input for `muxmymeta`.

I also used `rtpgstpay` and `rtpgstdepay` elements to use this new media type with RTP/RTSP. You will NOT need to write a typefinding function at this point since `rtpgstpay`/`rtpgstdepay` will be able to figure that out from the caps. This works well out of the box for h265 streams in gstreamer v1.6.2 but I had to make a fix inside gstreamer itself to make it work with h264 as well. Finally, to make autopluggers such as `decodebin`/`uridecodebin` to decode your stream, you must set the klass for `demuxmymeta` to `Codec`/`Decoder`/`Demuxer` and set a priority for it other than none, this basically tells gstreamer to use this element for decoding.

Here are 2 pipelines for illustration:

1. Sending H265 RTSP with metadata pipeline (set as the launch line for `GstRTSPMediaFactory`)
   `( rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test latency=0 ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! muxmymeta ! rtpgstpay name=pay0 pt=96 )`

Here, the `rtsp://localhost:8554/test` stream is a regular h265 stream `video/x-h265`. yet assume that the rtsp-server will produce `rtsp://localhost:8553/test-meta` which has the type `video/x-h265-with-meta`

2. Receiver
   `rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8553/test-meta ! rtpgstdepay ! demuxmymeta ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

With an Autoplugger it will look as neat as:
`uridecodebin uri=rtsp://localhost:8553/test-meta ! autovideosink`

Though this might seem like a longshot solution, it provides a way to transport self-synchronizing metadata between pipelines over the network.

Comment: can you share please the code? @Eslam